# I need to integrate vimeo pro videos on my site

Tags: angularjs, vimeo, videogular

I have a site that i build, with no cms like joomla/wordpress.

I have laravel on the server, angular on the front.

Now i have a survey builder, let's people add this and that kind of questions and let other participating in the survey.

Now i want my customers to be able to integrate their vimeo pro videos on my site, currently the only videos im allowing is mp4 ones, for which im using videogular.

Is there any ways to let my customers integrate vimeo Pro videos in my site with such ease?

Answer (score 0):

You could try letting them to embed their players or create a videogular plugin to embed vimeo video player inside of videogular.

Take a look to the JavaScript API and to the embedding documentation available at the vimeo website:

http://developer.vimeo.com/player